# How to do SSH tunnelling for AWS Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I have the following setup:

1. A VPC
2. Two private subnets and 1 public subnet
3. A bastion in the public subnet
4. A private hosted zone
5. A private Load Balancer
6. EC2 instances (running the application) in private subnets behind the ALB

Since, bastion is the only resource in the public subnet I, need to access my application running in private EC2 instances. For this I am using the ssh tunneling as below:

```
ssh -L 9443:<PRIVATE-IP-OF-AN-EC2>:9443 test-v2-tunnel -N -v
```

here's the `test-v2-tunnel` is located inside the ~/.ssh/config as below:

```
Host test-v2-tunnel
  Hostname <BASTION-PUBLIC-IP-RETRACTED>
  user ec2-user
  IdentityFile /Users/jananath/.ssh/CustomerSSH/TFL/key.pem
```

The tunneling works but it is pointing to only one IP of a node. But I need to give the domain name (in the local hosted zone) instead.

Because within in the VPC, the applications in all the instances are talking to each other through domains in the private hosted zone. Therefore for your better understanding, the traffic flow is like this:

`Traffic hits domain in the private hosted zone` -> `goes to the Load Balancer` -> `goes to the relevant target group based on the host-header defined in ALB listener` -> `goes to the instance behind the target group`

But according to my `ssh` command, it only directs traffic to the `ip` of an instance.

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
ssh -L 9443:apim.test.local test-v2-tunnel -N -v
```

where `apim.test.local` is a record set in the private hosted zone.

I tried this but it seems doesn't work.  Can you help me on this?

Comment: Have you configured DNS within the VPC to point `apim.test.local` to the DNS Name of the Load Balancer? If you SSH into the Bastion (without port forwarding) and `curl apim.test.local`, does it respond with anything? That will help you test whether the bastion can access the Load Balancer. If it is not working, then please tell us the configuration of the Inbound Security Group on the Load Balancer and the Outbound Security Group on the Bastion.

Comment: when I curl `apim.test.local` it gives me the landing page result.

Comment: I wonder if it is just missing the port? Try: `ssh -L 9443:apim.test.local:80 test-v2-tunnel -N -v`  You would then access it via `localhost:9443`

Comment: Did you figure this out?